Error : PydanticUserError: If you use `@root_validator` with pre=False (the default) you MUST specify `skip_on_failure=True`
Here is the code after loading data and creating index  I am trying to setup the chat engine:
index = load_and_index_data()

chat_engine = index.as_chat_engine(chat_mode="condense_question", verbose=True)

Macos, python = 3.12.4.
PydanticUserError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 index = load_and_index_data()
      3 chat_engine = index.as_chat_engine(chat_mode="condense_question", verbose=True)

Cell In[8], line 31
     29 # Create an index using the vector store
     30 storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)
---> 31 index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, storage_context=storage_context)
     32 return index



PydanticUserError: If you use `@root_validator` with pre=False (the default) you MUST specify `skip_on_failure=True`. Note that `@root_validator` is deprecated and should be replaced with `@model_validator`.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.8/u/root-validator-pre-skip
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

